# How disable button until all form is valid in react js?

Tags: reactjs, forms, function

How can the validation Login form be done before submitting,

And make the button disable until all form is valid in react js ( function component )?

I write this code and I do not know how can make the button disable until every single field is valid

also, I am a beginner in react js

any advice, please?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { emailValidator, passwordValidator } from "./regexValidator";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [isDisabled, setDisable] = useState(true);

  const [input, setInput] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const [errorPassword, seterrorPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorEmail, seterrorEmail] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput({ ...input, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const formSubmitter = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    onKey();

    navigate("/");
  };

  const onKey = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDisable(true);

    if (!emailValidator(input.email)) {
        seterrorEmail("Please enter valid email id");
      } else {
        seterrorEmail("");
      }
  
      if (!passwordValidator(input.password)) {
        seterrorPassword("Please enter valid password");
      } else {
        seterrorPassword("");
        setDisable(false);
      }
    
  };

  return (
          <form onSubmit={formSubmitter}>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onKeyUp={onKey}
              error={errorEmail}
            />

            <input
              name="password"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onKeyUp={onKey}
              error={errorPassword}
            />

                <button
                  type="button"
                  disabled={isDisabled}
                />
          </form>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the form by using the library or using useEffect.

My suggested library is React Hook Form. You can get it here - https://react-hook-form.com/

Also you can use Yup for validation - https://github.com/jquense/yup

By useEffect method:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {

 // Run your validation function
  
 // if all the data are valid, then enable the form
  
}, [name, email]) // Only re-run the effect if name or email change


// When the form submit button is clicked
function onHandleSubmit(){
  // check the name is empty or not
  // check if email is not empty and valid or not
  
  //if all form fields are valid, submit form value;
  submitForm(values);
}
```